# Hooking up the download from Ajax "GET"

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, web, frontend

A zip file will be downloaded on user button click. I have the following setup but I am having trouble how to get these pieces connected.

The "GET" call will return byte content with the content type set as `application/x-zip-compressed` and content disposition set as `attachment` with a filename `xxxx.zip`

```
$(".downloadBtn").on("click", function(){
  $.ajax({
    headers: {
      "xxxx" : "3.0"
    },
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
      // do something with the data
    },
    error: function(eData) {
      console.log(eData);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: so, what is the problem ... where are you stuck

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the expected answer, but you can try this as an alternative.

```
<a href="your_download_url.zip" download>
    <button>Download</button>
</a>
```

If you are using HTML5, this "download" attribute can be useful.

Comment: If the `content-disposition` header is set, I don't even think you would _need_ the download attribute.

Comment: Without download attribute, chances are there that you will be redirected to "path.zip" page.

Comment: I suppose there's a chance (if the request is from a browser that doesn't properly handle this type of response). But all modern browsers _should_ just download the file I think. Here's what MDN has to say... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Comment: @jessegavin, Yes. It makes sense.

Comment: @Nandan this is not what I am looking for and it's not working. I don't have the "download_url" but the request url that will be sent to the server to retrieve the zip file. I need a way to process the returned byte data and transform it to the zip file. When user click the button it will be downloaded. Hope that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Try putting the same URL in the href section.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the back end? Can you provide more information about the backend part?

Anyway assuming you are using some sort of web APIs to write some sort of front end only application, you could maybe use this Javascript [library](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) to create the file from bytes (Blob). It probably won't work on all browsers but it does on chrome, I tried it myself.

Comment: @ Luca Angioloni Thanks for the comment. I got this working now from one of the post on stackoverflow. And you're right, it's not working in all browsers. Looks like IE11 doesn't like it and decided to throw a "InvalidSTateError" at me. Per this [post](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/795580/ie11-xmlhttprequest-incorrectly-throws-invalidstateerror-when-setting-responsetype) that it's not repro but I got it. By chance you have a work around to this issue?

Comment: @JasonTang unfortunately I don't know any workaround for IE...as usual nothing works on IE...